# ssis 2017 throws exception on trying to debug script task

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Ive set Run64BitRunTime to false in the project debugging properties.  I cant seem to debug a script task.  It just blows chunks when I start up the debugger.

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

[ update ]
If I remove the code that I added, the script task will still not be stopped with the breakpoint set at the very beginning of main.  This makes me thing I am running in Release mode for some reason?  I'm adding the visual studio tag to this post, as I think its more than just ssis issue sinvolved, but I could be wrong.

As an experiement I started a blank SSIS project in VS 2017 using the BI project templates for SSIS, and I noticed the configuration manager only has one configuration.  Shouldnt there be two?  Debug and release?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to debug in a script task on the Control Flow.

I have been using `MessageBox.Show("put variable or something to indicate the position in the code.");`

for a lack of knowing any other way. Its not the best, but you have some process of elimination you can start using this.